# What does -J stand for in the jvm argument -J-Xmx?

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments

What does -J stand for in the jvm argument -J-Xmx ? I have always used -Xmx only and it is the first time I have come across 'J'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-J` flag is used by a few command-line tools, themselves written in Java, to let you pass command-line arguments directly to the JVM they're running in. So, for example, you can't pass "-Xmx1000m" as an argument to `javac.exe`, but you *can* pass "-J-Xmx1000m", and `javac.exe` will (effectively) use it as an option to `java.exe`.